# how do i check if php-fpm is serving php request

Tags: php, apache2.2, mod-fastcgi

i've installed php-fpm on Centos 5.8 + Apache2

So, the question is: how do i check if php-fpm is serving the php requests ?

With an index.php like this one below

```
echo "php-fpm test";
```

calling `http://localhost/index.php`  the output is fine, but

if I run

```
service php-fpm stop
```

the same call works fine anyway.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

You can install a package and try and connect. The package name is called `libfcgi`.

`cgi-fcgi  -bind -connect localhost:9000`

If I was to guess, you probably installed PHP to spawn workers that don't disconnect when FPM is stopped, or you are running both `/etc/init.d/php5-cgi` and `/etc/init.d/php-fpm`.

Comment: I haven't installed php5-cgi. What output i should expect from libfcgi ?

Comment: It just tries to connect. Since you aren't passing a script_name to it, it will just say some random headers and `No input file specified.
`

Comment: Ok. So, another info for you. phpinfo() show me that the **Server API** is **CGI/FastCGI**. Is it right ? Shouldn't be something like 'PhpFpm" ?